# The ununiqueness of UUID and GUID

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I recently created the tag [uuid](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uuid) because I thought it was missing. Then I discovered the [guid](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guid) tag. How to deal with these two?

They are sort of the same thing (at least they have the same [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)), so one tag should be enough. But since GUID is (a) not used as often, and (b) a Microsoft thing, I wouldn't want [guid](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guid) to be the main tag.

Could we make [guid](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guid) a synonym of [uuid](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uuid)? Or any better ideas?

Comment: The [guid] tag is gone. Seems like there has been a retagging effort to move to [uuid]. No synonym though, but I don't think it's really needed. I consider this case closed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm all for your suggestion. They are functionally identical.